# How can I determine the nett effect of all joining/leaving records in each group?

Tags: mysql, sequential

Slightly simplified, I have a table showing status records for members of an organisation. They join by becoming 'Active' and can leave by becoming 'Resigned', 'Lapsed' or 'Deceased'. Having one or more sequential leaving records only counts as having left only once, at the date of the earliest leaving record. Similarly with joining records if that were ever to occur.

Each change in status is recorded as one record using the member_id and the data of the change. A single member may have many status change records.

I need to be able to group by each member and determine if the overall result of all the records for a member in a given year, say 2015, results in a nett gain or loss for the organisation, hence making them a joiner or a leaver (or nothing if the effects cancel).
The result I want is (a) how many joiners and who they are and (b) how many leavers and who they are.

**Can anyone help me with the correct coding techniques to process all the records of a member in sequential, chronological order in order to determine the nett result for that member?**

An example schema and data is below - see also SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69feb5/1

```
CREATE TABLE memstatus (
  member_id INT,
  date_assigned DATE,
  status_type VARCHAR(10));


INSERT INTO memstatus (member_id, date_assigned, status_type)
VALUES
(178,   '1948-01-01',   'Active'),
(178,   '2015-02-12',   'Deceased'),

(190,   '2013-12-09',   'Active'),
(190,   '2014-03-23',   'Resigned'),
(190,   '2015-12-09',   'Active'),

(194,   '2013-01-01',   'Active'),
(194,   '2015-03-15',   'Lapsed'),
(194,   '2015-08-20',   'Active'),

(935,   '2015-04-01',   'Active'),

(214,   '1966-01-01',   'Active'),
(214,   '2015-01-09',   'Lapsed'),
(214,   '2015-08-10',   'Deceased')

(300,   '2015-01-09',   'Active'),
(300,   '2015-07-10',   'Resigned')
```

The results from this data should be

**Joiners in 2015**

id 190   {left before 2015 but re-joined in 2015}

id 935   {new member in 2015}

**Leavers in 2015**

id 178   {one leaving record in 2015}

id 214   {two sequential leaving records in 2015 - but must count as one}

**neither leaver nor joiner**

id 194 {left but re-joined in the same year}

id 300 {joined and left in the same year}

I tried the following for leavers (see SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69feb5/1) but this only works if the last record is a leaving record so gives me member 300 as well. I had the same problem with joiners.

```
SELECT member_id, status_type, date_assigned
FROM memstatus
WHERE date_assigned = (SELECT MAX(date_assigned) 
                                    FROM memstatus AS T1 
                                    WHERE T1.member_id = memstatus.member_id 
                                    AND   T1.date_assigned BETWEEN CONCAT('2015','-01-01') AND CONCAT('2015','-12-31')
                                    )

 AND  status_type NOT LIKE 'Active'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT member_id, assigned_year, 
CASE 
    WHEN finalStatus <0 THEN 'Leaver'
    WHEN finalStatus >0 THEN 'Joiner'
    WHEN finalStatus =0 THEN 'Neither'
END 
FROM (Select member_id, Year(date_assigned) AS assigned_year, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN status_type_id = 'Active' THEN 1
        WHEN status_type = 'Resigned' THEN -1
        WHEN status_type = 'Lapsed' THEN -1
        WHEN status_type = 'Deceased' THEN -1
    END) AS finalStatus
    FROM memstatus 
    GROUP BY member_id, Year(date_assigned) 
    ) As a
ORDER BY member_id`

Comment: Thank you, that not only does what I want but gives me a result that is useful for further processing. Clever idea using SUM(). I was getting so frustrated that it was obvious how to do it manually but I couldn't really work out exactly what my brain was doing in order to translate it into SQL  (BTW I've edited my question to make the status_type field name match that in the SQLFiddle and edited your answer in the same way to make your field name match the question but that edit has to wait for peer review before it becomes visible - whatever that implies.)

Comment: An upvote along with the approved answer would be nice 8)
Thanks

Comment: Sorry Edward, I didn't realise I could give both. I thought approving an answer automatically upvoted your status. I've done it now.